# How do I calculate the standard deviation of response times in a SOAP UI LoadTest?

Tags: soapui, load-testing, standard-deviation

The only metrics saved at the end of a LoadTest are min/max/average - this gives no indication of the spread of response times.

I'd like to get the standard deviation - is there anyway to do this?

I'm using the Open Source version of SOAP UI.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: If all you have access to is those three metrics (and not the underlying samples) then you can't calculate SD.

Comment: How would I get the individual responses?

Comment: Well, you do mention that it's open source...